# Reposition correctly using only CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get these positioned like so:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/ut1mgcLb/

HTML

```
<div class="object1">
    <div class="snax-voting-container-body">
        <div class="snax-voting snax-voting-positive snax-voting-large" data-snax-item-id="297">
            <div class="snax-voting-score">
                <strong>6203</strong> points
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="snax-voting-upvote snax-vote snax-vote-up snax-guest-voting" title="Upvote" data-snax-item-id="297" data-snax-author-id="0" data-snax-nonce="6bb412040e"><span class="snax-vote-icon snax-vote-icon-caret"></span> Upvote</a>
            <a href="#" class="snax-voting-downvote snax-vote snax-vote-down snax-guest-voting" title="Downvote" data-snax-item-id="297" data-snax-author-id="0" data-snax-nonce="6bb412040e"><span class="snax-vote-icon snax-vote-icon-caret"></span> Downvote</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href=" https://themeforest.net/item/bimber-viral-buzz-wordpress-theme/14493994 "><img id="postTB" src=" https://i.imgur.com/Nf57W2G.jpg"></a><a href=" https://themeforest.net/item/bimber-viral-buzz-wordpress-theme/14493994 "> 25 Delicious Things To Cook In September (themeforest.net)</a><img alt="" src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/9f221658beaba2ee853f978fa48f49c2?s=40&amp;r=g&amp;d=retro" srcset="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/9f221658beaba2ee853f978fa48f49c2?s=40&amp;r=g&amp;d=retro 2x" class="avatar avatar-40 photo" height="40" width="40">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#postTB{
  width:10%;
}
```

Is there a way to reposition these correctly using only CSS, or do I need to start over with the HTML ordering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remade without `display: contents`

```css
#postTB{
 width: 100%;
}

 .object1 {
   display: flex;
  }

 .object1 a {
   width: 10%;
  }

 .object1 a:last-of-type {
   width: auto;
  }

  .snax-voting {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   text-align: center;
   }
```

```html
<div class="object1">
    <div class="snax-voting-container-body">
        <div class="snax-voting snax-voting-positive snax-voting-large" data-snax-item-id="297">
            <div class="snax-voting-score">
                <strong>6203</strong> points
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="snax-voting-upvote snax-vote snax-vote-up snax-guest-voting" title="Upvote" data-snax-item-id="297" data-snax-author-id="0" data-snax-nonce="6bb412040e"><span class="snax-vote-icon snax-vote-icon-caret"></span> Upvote</a>
            <a href="#" class="snax-voting-downvote snax-vote snax-vote-down snax-guest-voting" title="Downvote" data-snax-item-id="297" data-snax-author-id="0" data-snax-nonce="6bb412040e"><span class="snax-vote-icon snax-vote-icon-caret"></span> Downvote</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href=" https://themeforest.net/item/bimber-viral-buzz-wordpress-theme/14493994 "><img id="postTB" src=" https://i.imgur.com/Nf57W2G.jpg"></a><a href=" https://themeforest.net/item/bimber-viral-buzz-wordpress-theme/14493994 "> 25 Delicious Things To Cook In September (themeforest.net)</a><img alt="" src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/9f221658beaba2ee853f978fa48f49c2?s=40&amp;r=g&amp;d=retro" srcset="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/9f221658beaba2ee853f978fa48f49c2?s=40&amp;r=g&amp;d=retro 2x" class="avatar avatar-40 photo" height="40" width="40">
</div>
```

```css
#postTB{
  width:10%;
}

.object1 {
   display: flex;
}

.object1 a {
   display: contents;
}
```

```html
<div class="object1">
    <div class="snax-voting-container-body">
        <div class="snax-voting snax-voting-positive snax-voting-large" data-snax-item-id="297">
            <div class="snax-voting-score">
                <strong>6203</strong> points
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="snax-voting-upvote snax-vote snax-vote-up snax-guest-voting" title="Upvote" data-snax-item-id="297" data-snax-author-id="0" data-snax-nonce="6bb412040e"><span class="snax-vote-icon snax-vote-icon-caret"></span> Upvote</a>
            <a href="#" class="snax-voting-downvote snax-vote snax-vote-down snax-guest-voting" title="Downvote" data-snax-item-id="297" data-snax-author-id="0" data-snax-nonce="6bb412040e"><span class="snax-vote-icon snax-vote-icon-caret"></span> Downvote</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href=" https://themeforest.net/item/bimber-viral-buzz-wordpress-theme/14493994 "><img id="postTB" src=" https://i.imgur.com/Nf57W2G.jpg"></a><a href=" https://themeforest.net/item/bimber-viral-buzz-wordpress-theme/14493994 "> 25 Delicious Things To Cook In September (themeforest.net)</a><img alt="" src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/9f221658beaba2ee853f978fa48f49c2?s=40&amp;r=g&amp;d=retro" srcset="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/9f221658beaba2ee853f978fa48f49c2?s=40&amp;r=g&amp;d=retro 2x" class="avatar avatar-40 photo" height="40" width="40">
</div>
```

Comment: to be picky, display:contents; hasn't a good [support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents)

Comment: @Sfili_81, remade without display: contents (second snippet)

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: flex` to your container and resize the image whatever you want

```
.object1{
display:flex;
}
```

codepen : https://codepen.io/the-wrong-guy/pen/VweEqXx?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the css flexbox? My goto cheetsheet is here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

You can specify ordering with flexbox, so you'd just do inline-flex, flex direction column, and then manually set the order
ex:

```
.snax-voting-container-body {
  display: inline;
}

.snax-voting {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.snax-voting a {
  display: block;
}

.snax-voting-upvote {
  order: 0;
}
.snax-voting-score {
  order: 1;
}
.snax-voting-downvote {
  order: 2;
}
```